# Using data.table package inside my own package

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to use the data.table package inside my own package.  MWE is as follows:

I create a function, test.fun, that simply creates a small data.table object, and then sums the "Val" column grouping by the "A" column.  The code is

```
test.fun<-function ()
{
    library(data.table)
    testdata<-data.table(A=rep(seq(1,5), 5), Val=rnorm(25))
    setkey(testdata, A)
    res<-testdata[,{list(Ct=length(Val),Total=sum(Val),Avg=mean(Val))},"A"]
    return(res)
}
```

When I create this function in a regular R session, and then run the function, it works as expected.

```
> res<-test.fun()
data.table 1.8.0  For help type: help("data.table")
> res
     A Ct      Total        Avg
[1,] 1  5 -0.5326444 -0.1065289
[2,] 2  5 -4.0832062 -0.8166412
[3,] 3  5  0.9458251  0.1891650
[4,] 4  5  2.0474791  0.4094958
[5,] 5  5  2.3609443  0.4721889
```

When I put this function into a package, install the package, load the package, and then run the function, I get an error message.

```
> library(testpackage)
> res<-test.fun()
data.table 1.8.0  For help type: help("data.table")
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i, j) : object 'Val' not found
```

Can anybody explain to me why this is happening and what I can do to fix it.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that you haven't declared a dependency. You should remove `library(data.table)` from your function, and declare `depends:data.table` in your namespace and DESCRIPTION.

Comment: There is also now the `.datatable.aware = TRUE` option to handle this issue, as discussed in [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2341#issuecomment-328084921) issue and in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html) linked below. Declaring `Depends: data.table` will attach the whole package to the search path, which is sometimes [discouraged](https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#search-path).

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Andrie's guess is right, +1. There is a FAQ on it (see `vignette("datatable-faq")`), as well as a new [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html) on importing `data.table`:

> *FAQ 6.9: I have created a package that depends on data.table. How do I
>   ensure my package is data.table-aware so that inheritance from
>   data.frame works?*
>
> Either i) include `data.table` in the `Depends:` field of your DESCRIPTION file, or ii) include `data.table` in the `Imports:` field of your DESCRIPTION file AND `import(data.table)` in your NAMESPACE file.

Further background ... at the top of `[.data.table` (and other `data.table` functions), you'll see a switch depending on the result of a call to `cedta()`. This stands for Calling Environment Data Table Aware. Typing `data.table:::cedta` reveals how it's done. It relies on the calling package having a namespace, and, that namespace Import'ing or Depend'ing on `data.table`. This is how `data.table` can be passed to non-*data.table-aware* packages (such as functions in `base`) and those packages can use absolutely standard `[.data.frame` syntax on the `data.table`, blissfully unaware that the `data.frame` `is()` a `data.table`, too.

This is also why `data.table` inheritance didn't used to be compatible with namespaceless packages, and why upon user request we had to ask authors of such packages to add a namespace to their package to be compatible. Happily, now that R adds a default namespace for packages missing one (from v2.14.0), that problem has gone away :

> CHANGES IN R VERSION 2.14.0
>   *  All packages must have a namespace, and one is created on installation if not supplied in the sources.

Comment: (Sorry to revive this, but...) Matthew, can you clarify how this would work from an interactive standpoint? If my package returns a `data.table` to a user in an interactive session, will they be required to use the `data.table` semantics, or is there some way I could support the familiar `data.frame` syntax?

Comment: @JeffAllen That's a new one...not sure.  If your package Depends on data.table then that'll make the user data.table aware I guess. Maybe Importing data.table wouldn't (and maybe that's what you'd like).

Comment: Thanks Matt! This solved my problem after half a day of failures and searching the net. I had put data.table only in the Imports. The code worked well in R but not from within the package. Moved to Depends and it works!

Comment: @OskarHansson Glad Depends works but Import should work as long as you had *both* Imports in DESCRIPTION *and* `import(data.table)` in NAMESPACE as well?

Comment: @MattDowle You are right. I got a NOTE when using Depends. I changed back to Imports + added `@import data.table` in the code so Roxygen adds `import(data.table)` in the NAMESPACE.

Comment: I had a problem with precisely the same symptoms but the above did not work. For whatever reason, `@import dtplyr` did help. Would be interested in knowing why.

Comment: @Jim Having to guess I'd guess it's the `roxygen2` extra layer (`@import`) not quite translating to precisely above. Have a look at `roxygen2`'s output to see if it has produced exactly above.

Answer (score 39):

Here is the complete recipe:

1. Add `data.table` to `Imports` in your `DESCRIPTION` file.
2. Add `@import data.table` to your respective .R file (i.e., the .R file that houses your function that's throwing the error `Error in [.data.frame(x, i, j) : object 'Val' not found`).
3. Type `library(devtools)` and set your working directory to point at the main directory of your R package.
4. Type `document()`.  This will ensure that your `NAMESPACE` file includes a `import(data.table)` line.
5. Type `build()`
6. Type `install()`

For a nice primer on what `build()` and `install()` do, see: http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/.

Then, once you close your R session and login next time, you can immediately jump right in with:

1. Type `library("my_R_package")`
2. Type the name of your function that's housed in the .R file mentioned above.
3. Enjoy!  You should no longer receive the dreaded `Error in [.data.frame(x, i, j) : object 'Val' not found`

Comment: I followed these instructions and I getting `function not found`. I could not find anything similar so I created a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720520/creating-custom-r-package-with-data-table-custom-function

Comment: Thank you for this. You helped me see what to do in an easy to read format.

Comment: Answers like these are the best!  In my case, though, I still had to add `.datatable.aware <- TRUE` somewhere in the package for this to work.