# data.table error when used through knitr, gWidgetsWWW

Tags: r, data.table, knitr, gwidgets

I'm experimenting with gWidgetsWWW and encountered a strange error. I created a button with a handler to knit2html a report which used the data.table assignment operator ":=".  The report came back with this error:

> Error: := is defined for use in j only, and (currently) only once; i.e.,
>   DT[i,col:=1L] and DT[,newcol:=sum(colB),by=colA] are ok, but not
>   DT[i,col]:=1L, not DT[i]$col:=1L and not DT[,{newcol1:=1L;newcol2:=2L}].
>   Please see help(":="). Check is.data.table(DT) is TRUE.

The report generates as expected using knit2html directly and also through RStudio's "Knit HTML" button, so I'm unsure why it fails when knit2html is called by the handler.

Here is a gWidgetsWWW window "test_gui.R":

```
library(gWidgetsWWW)
library(knitr)

w<-gwindow("Test Window")
g<-ggroup(horizontal=F,cont=w)
b<-gbutton("Report Button",cont=g,handler=function(h,...){
    knit2html("test_report.Rmd")
    localServerOpen("test_report.html")
})

visible(w)<-T
```

Here is an example R Markdown Doc which produces the error:

````
Test Report
===========

```{r test_chunk}
library(data.table)

df<-data.frame(State=rownames(USArrests),USArrests)

data.table(df)[,State:=tolower(State)]

```
````

Not sure why, but when I call localServerOpen("test_gui.R") and click the button, I get the error...

Any ideas?

Comment: This works on my machine. What version of `data.table` are you using?

Comment: `data.table(df)[,State:=tolower(State)]` is non standard usage. I think it would be safer to do `df <- as.data.table(df)` then `df[,State:=tolower(State)]` otherwise you are assigning by reference into an object I would not know how to reference.,

Comment: @Andrie Anonymous := (on an unnamed object) should be fine. I do that quite a lot. Can't think what's wrong since it works for you, and Zach has 1.8.2 ...

Comment: The line `localServerOpen("test_report.html")` should likely be `browseURL("test_report.html")`. You might also want to use gWidgetsWWW2 (on github). It has fewer issues than gWidgetsWWW and some more features.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at using gWidgetsWWW2 and switching over to browseURL() in place of localServerOpen() in those types of situations.

Comment: Hi. Quick reminder to accept an answer please. It's fixed in data.table. v1.8.6 now on CRAN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an environment issue. That is probably a problem between `data.table` and `gWidgetsWWW`. On `knitr`'s side, there is at least one solution, which is to specify the environment for `knitr` to be the global environment, e.g.

```
knit2html("test_report.Rmd", envir = globalenv())
```

**Edit:**

To illustrate this issue is irrelevant to `knitr`, try this:

```
library(gWidgetsWWW)

w<-gwindow("Test Window")
g<-ggroup(horizontal=F,cont=w)
b<-gbutton("Report Button",cont=g,handler=function(h,...){
  library(data.table)
  df<-data.frame(State=rownames(USArrests),USArrests)
  print(data.table(df)[,State:=tolower(State)])
})

visible(w)<-TRUE
```

Save it as `test_gui.R`, and

```
library(gWidgetsWWW)
localServerOpen('test_gui.R')
```

Click the button and you will also see the error.

Comment: Thanks Yihui, this does seem to address the problem.

Comment: That's interesting! See [this answer about cedta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10529888/403310) for background. I can see that `data.table` needs to be `knitr`-aware. On the other hand, I thought `knitr` mimicked exactly as if the R code was pasted at the console? I'm more than happy to make a change to `data.table`.

Comment: @MatthewDowle just figured out it is not a `knitr` issue; it seems to be related to `gWidgetsWWW` (I guess it is because of the environment in which `handler` is run; not completely sure); anyway, you can talk to @jverzani

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's looking like a `data.table` issue then, I'll take a look. Filed as [bug#2340](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2340&group_id=240&atid=975).

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Zach and Yihui, this is now fixed in data.table v1.8.3 on R-Forge.

```
o  gWidgetsWWW wasn't known as data.table aware, even though it mimics
   executing code in .GlobalEnv, #2340. data.table is now gWidgetsWWW aware.  
   Further packages can be added if required by changing a new variable
      data.table:::cedta.override
   by using assignInNamespace(). Thanks to Zach Waite and Yihui Xie for
   investigating and providing reproducible examples.
```

The full assignInNamespace command is :

```
assignInNamespace("cedta.override",
                  c(data.table:::cedta.override,"<nsname>"),
                  "data.table")
```

If you're not sure of the exact namespace name, set `options(datatable.verbose=TRUE)`, run the offending line again and an output message should tell you which namespace name was decided not to be data.table aware.

Asof the time of this edit, the packages on data.table's whitelist (v1.9.3) are :

```
> data.table:::cedta.override
[1] "gWidgetsWWW" "statET"      "FastRWeb"    "slidify"     "rmarkdown"
```

They tend to be packages which take user code as input and run that in their own environment.

Comment: It looks like `slidify` + `data.table` show the same problem as the OP question. Need to add a `assignInNamespace("cedta.override","slidify","data.table")` statement.

Comment: @mbask Missed your comment at the time, sorry. `slidify` now added. Thanks.

Comment: I have the problem with `slidify`.  Is it supposed to work nowadays ?

Comment: Ok it works now. I had to add `poirot` in the namespace.

Comment: Just for visibility I actually had to use "cedta.pkgEvalsUserCode" instead of "cedta.override" in the `assignInNamespace` call to get the `ezknitr` package to be data.table aware.

Comment: @MattMills Thanks. `ezknitr` now added: [#2266](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2266)