# What you can do with a data.frame that you can't with a data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I just started using R, and came across data.table. I found it brilliant.

A very naive question: Can I ignore data.frame to use data.table to avoid syntax confusion between two packages?

Comment: See [the data.table faq](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf) specifically 1.8 and 2.17. There will be cases where other packages may rely some  strange coding that falls down, but I haven't come across any (that haven't been fixed already).

Comment: @mnel I think your comment is the answer.

Comment: So this was 2.5 years ago... has anyone found something for which `data.frame` must be used yet??

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From the [data.table FAQ](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf)

### FAQ 1.8 OK, I'm starting to see what data.table is about, but why didn't you enhance data.frame in R? Why does it have to be a new package?

> As FAQ 1.1 highlights, `j` in `[.data.table` is fundamentally
>   different from `j` in `[.data.frame`. Even something as simple as
>   `DF[,1]` would break existing code in many packages and user code.
>   This is by design, and we want it to work this way for more
>   complicated syntax to work. There are other differences, too (see FAQ
>   2.17).
>
> Furthermore, `data.table` inherits from `data.frame`. It is a
>   `data.frame`, too. A `data.table` can be passed to any package that
>   only accepts `data.frame` and that package can use `[.data.frame`
>   syntax on the `data.table`.
>
> We have proposed enhancements to R wherever possible, too. One of
>   these was accepted as a new feature in R 2.12.0 :
>
> > `unique()` and `match()` are now faster on character vectors where all elements are in the global `CHARSXP` cache and have unmarked
> >     encoding (ASCII). Thanks to Matthew Dowle for suggesting improvements
> >     to the way the hash code is generated in `unique.`c.
>
> A second proposal was to use `memcpy` in `duplicate.c`, which is much
>   faster than a for loop in C. This would improve the way that R copies
>   data internally (on some measures by 13 times). The thread on r-devel
>   is here : http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e10/devel/10/04/0148.html.

### What are the smaller syntax differences between `data.frame` and data.table

> - `DT[3]` refers to the 3rd *row*, but `DF[3]` refers to the 3rd *column*
> - `DT[3, ] == DT[3]`, but `DF[ , 3] == DF[3]` (somewhat confusingly in data.frame, whereas data.table is consistent)
> - For this reason we say the comma is *optional* in `DT`, but not optional in `DF`
> - `DT[[3]] == DF[, 3] == DF[[3]]`
> - `DT[i, ]`, where `i` is a single integer, returns a single row, just like `DF[i, ]`, but unlike a matrix single-row subset which returns a vector.
> - `DT[ , j]` where `j` is a single integer returns a one-column data.table, unlike `DF[, j]` which returns a vector by default
> - `DT[ , "colA"][[1]] == DF[ , "colA"]`.
> - `DT[ , colA] == DF[ , "colA"]` (currently in data.table v1.9.8 but is about to change, see release notes)
> - `DT[ , list(colA)] == DF[ , "colA", drop = FALSE]`
> - `DT[NA]` returns 1 row of `NA`, but `DF[NA]` returns an entire copy of `DF` containing `NA` throughout. The symbol `NA` is type `logical` in R and is therefore recycled by `[.data.frame`. The user's intention was probably `DF[NA_integer_]`. `[.data.table` diverts to this probable intention automatically, for convenience.
> - `DT[c(TRUE, NA, FALSE)]` treats the `NA` as `FALSE`, but `DF[c(TRUE, NA, FALSE)]` returns
>     `NA` rows for each `NA`
> - `DT[ColA == ColB]` is simpler than `DF[!is.na(ColA) & !is.na(ColB) & ColA == ColB, ]`
> - `data.frame(list(1:2, "k", 1:4))` creates 3 columns, data.table creates one `list` column.
> - `check.names` is by default `TRUE` in `data.frame` but `FALSE` in data.table, for convenience.
> - `stringsAsFactors` is by default `TRUE` in `data.frame` but `FALSE` in data.table, for efficiency. Since a global string cache was added to R, characters items are a pointer to the single cached string and there is no longer a performance benefit of converting to `factor`.
> - Atomic vectors in `list` columns are collapsed when printed using `", "` in `data.frame`, but `","` in data.table with a trailing comma after the 6th item to avoid accidental printing of large embedded objects.
>     In `[.data.frame` we very often set `drop = FALSE`. When we forget, bugs can arise in edge cases where single columns are selected and all of a sudden a vector is returned rather than a single column `data.frame`. In `[.data.table` we took the opportunity to make it consistent and dropped `drop`.
>     When a data.table is passed to a data.table-unaware package, that package is not concerned with any of these differences; it just works.

---

### Small caveat

There will possibly be cases where some packages use code that falls down when given a data.frame, however, given that `data.table` is constantly being maintained to avoid such problems, any problems that may arise will be fixed promptly.

For example

- [see this question and prompt response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106018/data-table-error-when-used-through-knitr-gwidgetswww)
- From the NEWS for v 1.8.2

> - base::unname(DT) now works again, as needed by plyr::melt(). Thanks to
>     Christoph Jaeckel for reporting. Test added.
> - An as.data.frame method has been added for ITime, so that ITime can be passed to ggplot2
>         without error, #1713. Thanks to Farrel Buchinsky for reporting. Tests added.
>         ITime axis labels are still displayed as integer seconds from midnight; we don't know why ggplot2
>         doesn't invoke ITime's as.character method. Convert ITime to POSIXct for ggplot2, is one approach.

Comment: To my understanding of what is-a means, the code breaking semantic differences, mean that saying a data.table is a data.frame, only confuses me. Code that uses one needs to be edited before using the other correctly.

Comment: Basically, these are all benefits of Python Dataframe now covered in R through Data Tables, and also improved efficiency and clarity.