# What is the practical difference between data.frame and data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

Apparently in my last question I demonstrated confusion between `data.frame` and `data.table`.  Admittedly, I didn't realize there was a distinction.

So I read the help for each but in practical, everyday terms, what is the difference, what are the implications and what are each used for that would help guide me to their appropriate usage?

Comment: -1. Question is too broad.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, thanks, but it's also an opportunity for a genius to come up with a comprehensive and succint answer... :-)

Comment: @Justin: The links were helpful. I was unaware of them. Perhaps you could inform without the attitude. @Ferdinand.kraft: your second comment summarizes my position exactly. Of course I can read the help pages and tutorials, but many of them assume a working knowledge of the language and read like technical manuals for the experienced. Surely there is someone among us who can distill the most practical parts from having worked with both `data.frame` and `data.table` for years. I'm not looking to avoid work, merely what can the experienced programmers pass on to us with less experience?

Comment: This question has merit, lest you forget when you first learned a language

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618488/what-you-can-do-with-data-frame-that-you-cant-in-data-table/13635514#13635514

Answer (score 81):

While this is a broad question, if someone is new to `R` this can be confusing and the distinction can get lost.

All `data.table`s are also `data.frame`s.  Loosely speaking, you can think of data.tables as data.frames with extra features.

`data.frame` is part of base `R`.

`data.table` is a package that extends `data.frames`. Two of its most notable features are speed and cleaner syntax.

However, that syntax sugar is different from the standard R syntax for data.frame while being hard for the untrained eye to distinguish at a glance.  Therefore, if you read a code snippet and there is no other context to indicate you are working with data.tables and try to apply the code to a data.frame it may fail or produce unexpected results. (a clear giveaway that you are working with d.t's, besides the `library`/`require` call is the presence of the assignment operator `:=` which is unique to d.t)

With all that being said, I think **it is hard to actually appreciate the beauty of `data.table` without experiencing the shortcomings of `data.frame`**. (for example, see the first 3 bullet points of @eddi's answer).  In other words, I would very much suggest learning how to work with and manipulate `data.frames` first then move on to `data.table`s.

Answer (score 39):

A few differences in my day to day life that come to mind (in no particular order):

- not having to specify the `data.table` name over and over (leading to clumsy syntax and silly mistakes) in expressions (on the flip side I sometimes miss the TAB-completion of names)
- much faster and very intuitive `by` operations
- no more frantically hitting Ctrl-C after typing `df`, forgetting how large `df` was (also leading to almost never using `head`)
- faster and better file reading with `fread`
- the package also provides a number of other utility functions, like `%between%` or `rbindlist` that make life better
- faster everything else, since a lot of `data.frame` operations copy the entire thing needlessly

Comment: Is growing a `data.table` as slow (due to reallocation of memory) as growing a `data.frame`?

Comment: @Marcinthebox yes. Growing any contiguously allocated data structure is going to be slow.

Answer (score 10):

They are similar. Data frames are lists of vectors of equal length while data tables (`data.table`) is an inheritance of data frames. Therefore data tables are data frames but data frames are not necessarily data tables. The data tables package and function were written to enhance the speed of indexing, ordered joins, assignment, grouping and listing columns (etc.).

See http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-intro.pdf for more information.

Comment: They are similar in appearance only.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft they are not _similar_ in function?  ;)   But I agree that they have many differences