# getting an error when creating a lagged variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, lag

[related question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291988/r-how-to-create-a-lag-variable-for-each-by-group)

Hi, I have created a lagged variable using instructions from the answer to the above question (link above). It says that to create a lagged variable I need to use:

```
library(data.table)
 data = data[, lag.value:=c(NA, value[-.N]), by=groups]
```

Or, alternatively:

```
data = data[, lag.value :=  shift(value, 1L), keyby = groups]
```

This is what I got from the related questions answers below:

[related question 1 link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291988/r-how-to-create-a-lag-variable-for-each-by-group)

(I might be not entirely right with the second method because it is a bit complicated there so please correct me if it's wrong)

In any case as I use any of these methods I get an error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , `:=`(lag.value, c(NA,  : 
  unused argument (by = groups)
```

Could you please explain what I'm doing wrong here and what I should do to avoid the error?

data:

```
time  value   groups  
1      3        a
2      3        a
3      4        a
4      4        a
1      1        b
2      2        b
3      5        b
4      5        b
```

and the variable I want to create is lag.value which is value lagged by 1 within groups

Comment: I have installed the data.table package, but it's version is 1.9.4, and not 1.9.5 which seems to be necessary from what I understand for the second method. I'm also not sure why the package does not install with the highest current version?

Comment: What does your data looks like ?

Comment: I think your `data` is not of class `data.table`. You can do `setDT(data)` to make sure.

Comment: Yes, I think my data is data.frame . Is setting it to data.table not going to change anything else in the way I use it (accessing data etc)?

Comment: Ok, so from what I have read here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18002500/3745924)  data.table is an extension of data.frame, so It will be fine to change it without losing any functionality. Thanks, and this solves it @Frank

Comment: Glad that solved it. All the functionality is still available, but some of the syntax is different, like `DF[x]` and `DT[x]` will do different things; and `DF[,y]` vs `DT[,y]` I would recommend having a look at the intro docs for the package: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: also use 1.9.6 version, it is already available on CRAN