# Delete rows containing certain IDs in one dataset by using IDs identified in another dataset (in R)

Tags: r, function, reference, data-cleaning

I have a dataset of Chatrooms with people sending messages and a bigger dataset containing *both* these people *and* everyone else who did something besides go to a Chatroom.

I need to identify the people who were alone in the Chatrooms (in the chatroom dataset)—i.e., anyone in a chatroom with messages from only one person—and remove them from the bigger dataset.

So from the dataset below, I'd need to identify **Persons A, J,** and **M** and then remove those Persons from the bigger dataset (which also contains Persons A through Z and lots of other non-chat data).

```
data.table(Chatroom = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8), Person = c("A","A", "B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","J","J","K","L","M", "M"), Message = c("Hi", "You there?", "Hello", "Hi", "Hey", "Howdy", "Hi", "Hey", "Greetings", "Hi", "Hi", "Hello?", "Anyone there?", "Hey", "Hi", "Hello?", "Helllooooooo?"))

    Chatroom Person       Message
 1:        1      A            Hi
 2:        1      A    You there?
 3:        2      B         Hello
 4:        2      C            Hi
 5:        3      D           Hey
 6:        3      E         Howdy
 7:        4      F            Hi
 8:        4      G           Hey
 9:        5      H     Greetings
10:        5      I            Hi
11:        6      J            Hi
12:        6      J        Hello?
13:        6      J Anyone there?
14:        7      K           Hey
15:        7      L            Hi
16:        8      M        Hello?
17:        8      M Helllooooooo?
```

What R functions would help me do this?

I know how to create a list manually, but not from existing data based on criteria like what I mention above. I have used functions like mutate, glue, arrange, and drop_na, but I am struggling to imagine how to put these together to reproducibly filter the bigger dataset using the Chatroom subset.

**Advice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a small datatable `to_remove` like this:

```
to_remove = df[,ct:=uniqueN(Person), Chatroom][ct==1, .(Person=unique(Person))]
```

And then anti-join on your other data.table (say `df_big`), like this:

```
df_big[!to_remove, on="Person"]
```

I'm using data.table, since that is how you've provided `df`, but if you want an approach using `dplyr`, you can do this:

```
anti_join(
  df_big,
  df %>% group_by(Chatroom) %>% distinct(Person) %>% filter(n()==1),
  by = "Person"
)
```

Comment: Thanks! The first option is working on my actual dataframe, but only after I coerce the dataframe to be a datatable with `df -> data.table(df)`. I found some helpful info about the distinction between dataframes and datatables [in an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001120/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-data-frame-and-data-table-in-r).

Comment: yes, your frame must be data.table.., to set it in place, just use `setDT(df)`