# What does df[i] do?

Tags: r

What I have been teaching is that vectors are one dimensional, and data frames are two-dimensional. Hence, indexing on vectors requires one number - e.g., `v[1]` - and indexing on data frames requires two numbers - e.g., `df[1, 1]`.

I am learning from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13635514/3625022 that `df[1]`, for example, actually shows the first column of `df`. For example,

```
> x <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3)
> x[1]
  x
1 1
> x[,1]
[1] 1
```

I notice that these are slightly different, as `x[,1]` likely refers only to the vector of entries in the first column, whereas `x[1]` includes the row and column names.

Regardless, this contradicts the message that I have been stating - that data frames need two numbers for indexing. Is this statement incorrect? If it is correct, how does one explain to those new to `R` why `x[1]` gives the first column of `x`?

Comment: data.frame is a class that inherits from class list. Thus, list subsetting works for data.frames.

Comment: Note that `x[1]` is a `data.frame`, not a vector.

Comment: Everything in R is one-dimensional (that I know of). Data.frames are lists of columns; matrices are vectors shaped to look like something else; etc.

Comment: @Frank Matrices are vectors with a dim attribute. No "shape" involved.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for clarifying for the OP. I was perhaps explaining too loosely.

Comment: @Frank If OP is teaching it would be advantageous to understand the internal implementation of R data structures.

Comment: Thanks @Roland. Where can I learn more about these "inherited" classes (textbook, perhaps)? I'm admittedly not familiar with OOP (perhaps unsurprisingly, most of my work is procedural), but I am looking to learn more as time goes on. I have my hands on "Advanced R" by Wickham, and it looks like I may consider purchasing "Extending R" by Chambers in the future.

Comment: The [intro R manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html), is pretty dry an much of it you may already know, but it is full of useful insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data frames are lists.  A special type of list, to be sure, but they are lists.  `x[1]` is the first element of the list.  `x[[1]]` is the *contents* of the first element of the list, as is `x[,1]` when the list is a data frame.  Compare the output to an explicit list:

```
> x <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3)
> x[1]
  x
1 1
> x[[1]]
[1] 1
> x[,1]
[1] 1
> y = list(x=1, y=2, z=3)
> y[1]
$x
[1] 1

> y[[1]]
[1] 1
```