# RTVS: Unable to Knit Document with data.table

Tags: r, visual-studio, data.table, r-markdown, rtvs

I am trying to get a simple R Markdown document working with the [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) package in Visual Studio (RTVS) 2017 (15.7.4), to no avail.

Here is a minimum reproducible .rmd file (with some optional debug options turned on):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r knitr-setup, include = FALSE}
library(knitr)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = TRUE)
opts_knit$set(progress = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)

```

```{r test_id, message=FALSE, results="show", echo=TRUE, warning=FALSE}

require(rmarkdown)
require(data.table, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)


DT = data.table(x=1:3, y=4:6)    # no
DT                               # yes
DT[, z := 7:9]                   # no
print(DT[, z := 10:12])          # yes
if (1 < 2) DT[, a := 1L]         # no
DT                               # yes
```

Some text.

```{r}
sessionInfo()
```
````

I have looked at similar issues like these which have the same symptoms:

[data.table error when used through knitr, gWidgetsWWW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106018/data-table-error-when-used-through-knitr-gwidgetswww/13131555#13131555)

I have tried the namespace override similar to how I use it with "devtools" package development, doesn't seem to matter.

https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/278

As I thought it may be a problem with how I am referencing the package (or namespaces, etc, etc). However, the exact same file runs completely fine in "R Studio". So I am not sure that's the case.

The error I am getting is:

R Evaluation failed:

> rtvs::rmarkdown_publish(blob_id = 29, output_format = "html_document",
>   encoding = 'cp1252')
>
> Error in ':='(z, 7:9): Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE.
>   Otherwiese, := and ':=' are defined for us in j, once only and in
>   particular ways. See help(":=").

Again, this same document has no problems at all in *R Studio*.

I did notice the two shells call pandoc slightly different:

R Studio call:

> "C:/PROGRA~2/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS dt_error.utf8.md --to
>   html4 --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash+smart
>   --output dt_error.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\bmore\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html"
>   --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\bmore\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0cb9Vo\rmarkdown-stra0bc15f917ea.html"
>   --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"

Visual Studio Call:

> "C:/PROGRA~2/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS rmd_8c885bcf5786.utf8.md
>   --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash+smart
>   --output pandoc8c8870d27b22.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\bmore\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html"
>   --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\bmore\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp429dUm\rmarkdown-str8c886f7837b1.html"
>   --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"

I have also submitted a bug report to [Visual Studio Developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/284853/rtvs-error-kniting-r-markdown-with-datatable-packa.html), however, I am not entirely convinced it can't be resolved without changes to the IDE.

**Note**: *The above code runs in the IDE/Interactive mode fine, when attempting to 'knit' as any output type (html, pdf, doc), the error occurs.*

```
sessionInfo()
```

> R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United
>   States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) rmarkdown_1.10    knitr_1.20
>   ggplot2_2.2.1     dplyr_0.7.6       data.table_1.11.4
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) Rcpp_0.12.17
>   bindr_0.1.1      magrittr_1.5     rtvs_1.0.0.0     tidyselect_0.2.4
>   munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_1.3-2 R6_2.2.2         rlang_0.2.1
>   stringr_1.3.1    plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.5.0      grid_3.5.0
>   gtable_0.2.0     [15] htmltools_0.3.6  yaml_2.1.19
>   rprojroot_1.3-2  lazyeval_0.2.1   assertthat_0.2.0 digest_0.6.15
>   tibble_1.4.2     bindrcpp_0.2.2   purrr_0.2.5      evaluate_0.10.1 
>   glue_1.2.0       labeling_0.3     stringi_1.1.7    compiler_3.5.0

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: @Hugh added additional detail.

Comment: Does running `assignInNamespace("cedta.pkgEvalsUserCode", c(data.table:::cedta.pkgEvalsUserCode,"rtvs"), "data.table")` solve the issue?

Comment: @Hugh Ugh. Unbelievable. I tried this several times yesterday to no avail. I just reset the entire session, ran the binding, and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Lovely. Hopefully we'll have this patch included in the next release of data.table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is confirmed as fixed in `data.table_1.11.8` and later per @Hugh Ugh's comment above.

However, if anyone is constrained to use a prior version of data.table for some reason with RTVS, the workaround is to add:

```
assignInNamespace("cedta.pkgEvalsUserCode", c(data.table:::cedta.pkgEvalsUserCode, "rtvs"), "data.table")
```

In a script block, like so:

````
```{r additional-libraries, echo=FALSE}

    library(data.table, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

    assignInNamespace("cedta.pkgEvalsUserCode", c(data.table:::cedta.pkgEvalsUserCode, "rtvs"), "data.table")

    }
    ```
````