# Is assignInNamespace() the correct solution for errors rendering distill with data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, r-distill

Using the distill package and Rmarkdown for writing a blog, when rendering the .Rmd file I get errors when code chunks include data.table `:=` and `.`, but not functions such as  `data.table()`. The errors occur when the YAML header states `draft: false` but not when `draft: true`.

The R code chunk in the .Rmd file:

```
# create a data.table
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(p = 1:5, q = 6:10)

# operate with ":="
DT[, r := p + q][]

# operate with "."
DT[, .(p)]
```

With `draft: true` in the YAML header, the .Rmd file knits with no problem.

With `draft: false`, I can still run the R code chunks with no error but knitting the .Rmd file produces this error:

```
Error: Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, :=, `:=`(...) 
and let(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular 
ways. See help(":=").
Execution halted
```

If I comment out the line with the `:=` operation, knitting the document produces a similar error on the `.` operation:

```
Error in .(p) : could not find function "."
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> [ -> 
[.data.table -> [.data.frame
Execution halted
```

On Stackoverflow I found a similar issue 3 years ago with the rtvs package ([RTVS: Unable to Knit Document with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51122990/7245455)) that suggested a workaround using `assignInNamespace()`. I copied the suggestion to my code chunk and changed “rtvs” to “distill”, as follows:

```
# workaround    
assignInNamespace("cedta.pkgEvalsUserCode", 
                  c(data.table:::cedta.pkgEvalsUserCode, "distill"), 
                  "data.table")
```

The help page for `assignInNamespace()` says the function is intended for use within a package, which my blog is not, but it does solve my problem. Adding this workaround to the first code chunk eliminates the errors and the .Rmd file renders correctly.

My questions are:

1. Does using `assignInNamespace()` in this way produce any problematic side effects?
2. Is there another solution or is this possibly a case where data.table or distill might need a patch?

**Session information**

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.14.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fansi_1.0.2     digest_0.6.29   R6_2.5.1        jsonlite_1.7.3 
 [5] magrittr_2.0.2  evaluate_0.14   stringi_1.7.6   rlang_1.0.1    
 [9] cachem_1.0.6    cli_3.2.0       rstudioapi_0.13 jquerylib_0.1.4
[13] bslib_0.3.1     vctrs_0.3.8     rmarkdown_2.11  distill_1.3    
[17] tools_4.1.2     stringr_1.4.0   xfun_0.29       yaml_2.2.2     
[21] fastmap_1.1.0   compiler_4.1.2  memoise_2.0.1   htmltools_0.5.2
[25] knitr_1.37      downlit_0.4.0   sass_0.4.0
```

2022-06-06 Update.
I've switched blog-authoring software from distill to [quarto](https://quarto.org/). The problem described above does not occur with quarto and porting older posts to quarto has been fairly straightforward.