# Why might my non-interactive R session be dispatching a data.table as if it were a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a `data.table` object on which I'd like to do a simple lookup:

```
print(class(dt))
print(colnames(dt))
print(dt[region == "UK", ])
```

In my interactive R session, this chunk of code does exactly what it should.

```
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
[1] "region"            "site"              "visit"            
[4] "connectionfailure" "dnserror"          "http404"          
# ... output ...
```

In a non-interactive scripted session, I get a confusing error:

```
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
[1] "region"            "site"              "visit"            
[4] "connectionfailure" "dnserror"          "http404"          
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i, j) : object 'region' not found
```

It looks like R is dispatching `dt[....` to [[.data.frame](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/base/R/dataframe.R) rather than to [[.data.table](http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/data.table.R?view=markup&root=datatable).  Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: Most likely you don't have `library(data.table)` set up in your batch execution.  Could be something based on your user profile auto-loading `data.table`, but not batch exec.

Comment: @BrodieG, submit as answer?

Comment: BrodieG, to be clear: that would explain `"data.table"` showing as a class for `dt`, but the dispatch not working?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, with the extra work now I don't feel bad posting as an answer ;). sjbach, hopefully the answer addresses your question.

Comment: It's probably because the methods package isn't loaded automatically when Rscript starts.

Comment: try running `print(data.table:::cedta())` in your code (this is the command `data.table` runs internally to check if it should dispatch to `data.frame`) - might help ruling out a few things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posterity: in batch execution the problematic code is loaded from a custom package.  I neglected to include `import(data.table)` in my package's [`NAMESPACE`](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces) file.  I could be wrong, but I think this would still have worked if `data.table` didn't include an [explicit check](http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/cedta.R?view=markup&root=datatable) that the `[.data.table` calling environment includes `data.table` in its namespace, i.e. `data.table` is perhaps overreaching.  Still, I'm sure there must be a good reason for this check.

EDIT: More info about that explicit check here: 
[Using data.table package inside my own package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527072/using-data-table-package-inside-my-own-package/10529888#10529888)

Comment: If your package is not *data.table-aware*, `[.data.table` will dispatch to `[.data.frame`. Look at the first few lines of `data.table:::\`[.data.table\``

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you don't have `library(data.table)` set up in your batch execution. Could be something based on your user profile auto-loading `data.table`, but not batch exec.  Also, just b/c something has a class `data.table`, doesn't mean the package is loaded:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a=1:3)
detach("package:data.table", unload=TRUE)
class(dt)
# [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
setkey(dt, a)
# Error: could not find function "setkey"
library(data.table)
setkey(dt, a)
#works
```

Comment: This is a helpful answer, but unfortunately it doesn't lead to a solution in my case.  `setkey` and other `data.table` functions are defined and can be called without issue.  I don't know why, but the problem appears to be isolated to `[`.

Comment: @sjbach Do you see the `data.table` method when you do `methods("[")`?  Are you definitely loading data table explicitly?

Comment: An excellent follow-up question.  Alas, it is defined during the batch execution:
`... [5] [.data.table* ...` (printed directly prior to the indexing that throws the error)

Comment: Ah. With `options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)`, I get this warning during the indexing call: `cedta decided '<my package>' wasn't data.table aware`.  I don't know how to resolve that, but at least I have a lead.

Comment: @sjbach, cold comfort for you, but this works fine for me in batch mode.  I would recommend you try eddi's suggestion, and also reduce your script to the simplest possible reproducible exmaple (i.e. one line is `library(data.table)`, the next creates the `data.table`, the next one is your subset command, and that's it.  If that works, start adding complexity towards your original file and see what fails.