# data.table assignment by reference within function

Tags: r, reference, data.table

I have a (big-ish) `data.table`. And I want to do the same thing to many of its columns. Say,

```
dt <- data.table( ltr = letters[1:5] )
func <- function( dt ){
    cols <- colnames( dt ) # Columns to apply op to
    dt[ , (cols) := lapply( .SD, toupper ), .SDcols = cols ]
    return( dt )
}
```

The function `func` converts characters to upper case for all columns. I try

```
func( dt )
```

I get the error

```
Error in `:=`((cols), lapply(.SD, toupper)) : 
Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

I'm still not sure what causes the error and have read `help(":=")`, the FAQs and some other (SO) sources. Any help?

**NOTE: I should have given more details about the context. `func` is a function written in a package. That makes all the difference**

Comment: I'm not getting any error neither. Though, you need to be aware that your `dt` in the global environment is being updated by reference using `:=`. So no need in `return( dt )`. I would also suggest to explore `set` as it suites better for such operations.

Comment: Are you using this function from within a package? If so, [make sure your package is data.table aware](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10529888/559784)..

Comment: Option 2 seems to do the trick. I used roxygen2 for docs. `data.table` is listed in the `Imports` fields in DESCRIPTION but `import(data.table)` does not show up in NAMESPACE. Sad thing is I read and upvoted that answer :( Thanks, @Arun. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad it's resolved. You can answer it yourself, and accept it.

Comment: (@DavidArenburg :) Okay: back it goes.) The last line of this answer (suggested by Arun) illustrates the usage of `set` David mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16846530/1191259

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to [make sure the package is data.table aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10529888/1965432). See @Arun's comment.

Note that using `devtools::use_package( "data.table", pkg = "." )` will add to the `Imports` field in `DESCRIPTION` but not explicitly `import( data.table )` in NAMESPACE. As such, including `data.table` in the `Depends` field -- that's the first option Matthew outlines in his post -- may be more foolproof.