# dplyr masks GGally and breaks ggparcoord

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, ggally, parallel-coordinates

Given a fresh session, 
executing a small *ggparcoord(.)* example provided in the documentation of the function

```
library(GGally)

data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
diamonds.samp <- diamonds[sample(1:dim(diamonds)[1], 100), ]
ggparcoord(data = diamonds.samp, columns = c(1, 5:10))
```

results into the following plot:

[image]

Again, starting in a fresh session and executing the same script with the loaded *dplyr*

```
library(GGally)
library(dplyr)

data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
diamonds.samp <- diamonds[sample(1:dim(diamonds)[1], 100), ]
ggparcoord(data = diamonds.samp, columns = c(1, 5:10))
```

results in:

> Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Note that the order of the *library(.)* statements does **not** matter.

Questions

1. Is there something wrong with the code samples?
2. Is there a way to overcome the problem (over some namespace functions)?
3. Or is this a bug?

I need both *dplyr* and *ggparcoord(.)* in a bigger analysis but this minimal example reflects the problem i am facing.

Versions

- R      @ 3.2.3
- dplyr  @ 0.4.3
- GGally @ 1.0.1
- ggplot @ 2.0.0

**UPDATE**

To wrap the excellent answer given by Joran up:

Answers

1. The code samples are in fact wrong as *ggparcoord(.)* expects a *data.frame* not a *tbl_df* as given by the diamonds data set (if dplyr is loaded).
2. The problem is solved by coercing the *tbl_df* to a *data.frame*.
3. No it is not a bug.

**Working code sample:**

```
library(GGally)
library(dplyr)

data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
diamonds.samp <- diamonds[sample(1:dim(diamonds)[1], 100), ]
ggparcoord(data = as.data.frame(diamonds.samp), columns = c(1, 5:10))
```

Comment: I have everything the same but GGally @ 1.0.0 and I have the same error in both code

Comment: Did you reload the sessions between both code samples? Instead of reloading the session you can also detach the dplyr package (could be considered a workaround).

Comment: The GGally package here is making the reasonable assumption that using `[` on a data frame should behave the way it always does and always has. However, this all being in the Hadley-verse, the diamonds data set is a `tbl_df` as well as a `data.frame`. When `dplyr` is loaded, the behavior of `[` is overridden such that `drop = FALSE` is always the default for a `tbl_df`. So there's a place in GGally where `data[,"cut"]` is expected to return a vector, but instead it returns another data frame.

Comment: ...specifically, the error is thrown in your example while attempting to execute: `data[, fact.var] <- as.numeric(data[, fact.var])`. Since `data[,fact.var]` remains a data frame, and hence a list, `as.numeric` won't work.

Comment: That is awesome.  Nice two comments btw. Make them an answer!

Comment: Thanks for the fast and good answer!

Comment: @joran make a pull request to GGally. :)

Comment: This totally is a bug! `GGally::ggparcoord() breaks whenever `dplyr` is loaded. Unless you workaround by coercing your data to `as.data.table(... )` possibly with `..., keep.rownames=TRUE` unless you want to lose all your rownames.

Comment: @joran great job diagnosing. Can you please file a [GGally issue](https://github.com/ggobi/ggally/issues) and make a pull request?

Comment: @smci Looks like it's already been fixed. They switched from `[` to `[[` which is probably best anyway.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Converting my comments to an answer...

The GGally package here is making the reasonable assumption that using `[` on a data frame should behave the way it always does and always has. However, this all being in the Hadley-verse, the `diamonds` data set is a `tbl_df` as well as a `data.frame`.

When **dplyr** is loaded, the behavior of `[` is overridden such that `drop = FALSE` is always the default for a `tbl_df`. So there's a place in **GGally** where `data[,"cut"]` is expected to return a vector, but instead it returns another data frame.

...specifically, the error is thrown in your example while attempting to execute:

```
data[, fact.var] <- as.numeric(data[, fact.var]).
```

Since `data[,fact.var]` remains a data frame, and hence a list, `as.numeric` won't work.

As for your conclusion that this isn't a bug, I'd say....maybe. Probably. At least there probably isn't anything the **GGally** package author ought to do to address it. You just have to be aware that using `tbl_df`'s with non-Hadley written packages may break things.

As you noted, removing the extra class attributes fixes the problem, as it returns R to using the normal `[` method.

Comment: For those wondering, this doesn't happen for `data.table`.  Although `data.table` also overrides `[` it has a mechanism for automatic compatibility  with packages expecting a `data.frame`, described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10529888/403310).

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround:** coerce your data for `ggparcoord` to `as.data.table(...)` or `as.data.table(... , keep.rownames=TRUE)` unless you want to lose all your rownames.

**Cause:** as per @joran's investigating, when `dplyr` is loaded, `tbl_df` overrides `[` so that drop = FALSE.

<s>**Solution:** file a pull-request on GGally.</s>
edit: fixed in v1.3.0 (https://github.com/ggobi/ggally/commit/bfa930d102289d723de2ce9ec528baf42b3b7b40)