# Using `:=` from data.table when data.table package is not loaded?

Tags: r, data.table, package, loading, require

I want to use := operator from data.table without loading data.table. For example for the following data.table, I want to add another column called `error`:

```
DT <- data.table::data.table(station = rep(1:1,52560), mod = rnorm(1*52560),obs = rnorm(1*52560))
```

If I do the following everything goes well, however, I am puzzled how it worked without referring to package data.table (the data.table library is not loaded)?!!

```
DT[ , `:=`(error  = mod - obs)]
```

How can I rewrite the above line using data.table:::`:=` ?!!

Comment: what is the purpose of creating a data table object if you aren't using any of its features

Comment: If you want to include all references to data.table functions, you would need `[.data.table` as well.  But I agree with rawr, just load the package.

Comment: Isn't `:=` just `data.table::set` in a roundabout fashion?

Comment: I am going to use this in another package and preferably I want not to load data.table.

Comment: If you are going to use data.table syntax in a package, I would recommend you import the entire package.  I've done it. It's much safer, less worries.

Comment: @thelatemail could you give an example how to use, I do find any example. However, the main question here is how it works eventhough I have not loaded the library

Comment: @RichardScriven I am importing the package, I have no other choice since data.table will not work if I do not import. Would importing alone take care of this?

Comment: @newbie - `data.table::set(DT, i=NULL, j="blah", value=1)` - accessing column names will probably require `[.data.table` anyway though.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand correctly, but regarding :

> I am going to use this in another package and preferably I want not to load data.table. – newbie
>
> I am importing the package, I have no other choice since data.table will not work if I do not import. Would importing alone take care of this? – newbie

Yes Import data.table rather than Depend on it from your package. You may have tried that and it didn't work because of this common issue. See solution here :

[Using data.table package inside my own package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10529888/403310)

Comment: I have already import data.table to my package. I know for some of the commands such as as.data.table I have to use data.table::as.data.table but some other commands like  DT[ , `:=`(error  = mod - obs)], it will work automatically without me specifying it is from data.table package. That is what I am puzzled, why this happens?

Comment: "import data.table" is too imprecise wording given the detail of the linked question.  You do not have use the prefix in data.table::as.data.table. I don't follow what you're asking.  Why what happens?  Suspect English is not your first language.  Please take 2 hours to read https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support and _all_ its links and confirm you've done so.