# Error in package depending on another package that depends on data.table

Tags: r, dependencies, data.table, r-package

I have a behaviout that makes no sense to me, could someone explain the following bahaviour

I have created 2 packages `A,B`

`A` depends on `data.table` and defines the function `readFile`

`B` depends on `A` and defines the function `useFile`

```
useFile <- function(path){
  DT <- readFile(path)
  print(class(DT))
  return(DT[x == 'a'])
}
```

When I do

```
library(A)
library(B)
useFile(myFile)
```

**I see that DT is a `data.table`** from the `print` statement but it crashes saying that `object x not found` (of course the data.table has a x column)

Now when I also make `B` depends on `data.table` it works fine !

Can someone explain the behaviour, I would assume that all the `data.table`ness should be there when `library(A)` is called !!

PS: I know I should supply reproducible but we are taking 2 packages here, if there is no obvious answer I will upload 2 packages online

Comment: Package data.table should usually be in Imports in the DESCRIPTION file and be imported in the NAMESPACE of your first package. You should then either import your first package into your second package or import data.table there too. If I'm uptodate, depending on packages in contrast to importing them is usually not recommended anymore.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527072/using-data-table-package-inside-my-own-package Does your error state `Error in ``[.data.frame``(x, i, j) : object 'x not found`

Comment: @mnel: not this message but that's the pb yes, though I use Rstudio and roxygen2 to do all for me. I guess data.table NEEDS to be in imports in my case then ?

Comment: Most importantly, you must import data.table into the package's namespace. I think you can do that indirectly, i.e. import data.table's namespace into package1's namespace and then package1's namespace into package2's namespace, but I have never tried that. With roxygen2 you can just do `@import data.table`.

Comment: please provide NAMESPACE files of both packages, the part related to data.table

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527072/using-data-table-package-inside-my-own-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure, add 
`Depends: data.table` in `DESCRIPTION` to all packages that use `data.table` even if other packages they use already use `data.table`