# using data.table functions in custom package

Tags: r, data.table

I have a custom package but I'm having trouble using data.table inside functions. I've included `data.table` in the `Imports` file: [Using data.table package inside my own package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527072/using-data-table-package-inside-my-own-package)

If I save this funciton in the global enviroment it runs no-problem but now when called from the pacakge.

The error is:

> Error in `:=`(shapeId, paste(shape1, shape3, sep = "-")) : 
>     Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=")

However if I go into `browser()` mode to where this problem occurs, I find that running `is.data.table(res)` returns `TRUE`:
For replication:

```
res = structure(list(shape1 = c("oh", "sd", "tx", "tx", "tx", "tx"), 
    shape3 = c("pike", "aurora", "kendall", "kendall", "kendall", 
    "kendall")), .Names = c("shape1", "shape3"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

and then run

```
res[, shapeId := paste(shape1, shape3, sep = '-')]
```

triggers the error . Even though

```
Browse[2]>is.data.table(res)
Browse[2]>TRUE
```

Comment: Use `setDT(res)` after you recreated `res` with `structure(list ...`

Comment: that structure was the result of a `dput(res)` after running `setDT(res)`, `res` is already a `data.table`.

Comment: I know. But I would like to see what happens when you run `setDT(res)[, shapeId := paste(shape1, shape3, sep = '-')]`. I suspect your error will go away.

Comment: Please check out Jan's recent vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html

Comment: the error is still there

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Could include a self contained example that reproduces the error?