# setDT, Error in x[j]: invalid subscript type 'list', when executed as part of a function

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data frame with event records with Start Times and End Times.
I want to expand the records into multiple records of consistant time intervals, let's say hour long intervals.
For example, lets say the data frame contains two records:

```
EventId   Day   StartTime   EndTime
1         Mon   1           3
2         Tues  2           5
```

My desired new data frame should look like this

```
EventId   Day    Time
1         Mon    1
1         Mon    2
2         Tues   2
2         Tues   3
2         Tues   4
```

My function uses data.table::setDT to expand the records like this:

```
makeIncrementalRecords <- function(df) {
    new <- data.table::setDT(df)[,
                                 .(Time = seq(StartTime,
                                              EndTime,
                                              by = 1)),
                                 by = .(EventId, Day)]
```

Executing this line by line, I have no issues, and I get the result I want.  When I execute the function as part of a loaded package, I get the following error...

```
Error in x[j]: invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I am completely baffled as to why this code would suddenly stop working when executed as a function.  I guess it has something to do with the local function environment.  It works when I create the data frame as 'df' in the global environment and just execute the setDT function in the console.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, as the question states, I am calling this as a function that is part of a package I have created.  The code works if just run directly in a script, but called as a function, I get the error.  I am loading data.table as part of the package.

Comment: Sorry for my misreading. Maybe you know already, but there are some instructions for using data.table in a package here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10529888

Comment: Thanks Frank.  That was a big help.  It suddenly works by adding an @import to the roxygen comments for the function

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I think this result is what you are looking for.

```
structure(list(EventId = 1:2, Day = c("Mon", "Tues"), StartTime = 1:2, EndTime = c(3L, 5L)), 
          .Names = c("EventId", "Day", "StartTime", "EndTime"), 
          row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame") -> test_df 


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

generate_val <- function(startT, endT){
  (seq(from = startT, to = (endT-1), by = 1))
}

test_df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(new_vars = generate_val(.$StartTime, .$EndTime)) %>%
  bind_cols(test_df %>% select(-c(StartTime:EndTime))) %>%
  unnest()

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  EventId Day   new_vars
    <int> <chr>    <dbl>
1       1 Mon          1
2       1 Mon          2
3       2 Tues         2
4       2 Tues         3
5       2 Tues         4
```

To package this in a function you would have to follow the `NSE` procedure described here - [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

---

If you don't mind using `tidyr`, this should work. It might be a little slower than `data.table` for large datasets (rows > 1 million).

```
library(tidyr)

test_df %>%
  gather(., key = Time_type, value = Time, -EventId, -Day)

  EventId  Day Time_type Time
1       1  Mon StartTime    1
2       2 Tues StartTime    2
3       1  Mon   EndTime    3
4       2 Tues   EndTime    5
```

Comment: This doesn't get to the format I'm looking for.  I need to duplicate the record for each hour.  So, if the event spanned 4 hours, say, from 2 to 6, there needs to be 4 records, 1 for each hour 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Comment: You could mutate a list column with purrr and then unnest, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution similar to that proposed in the comments.

```
library(tidyverse)

makeIncrementalRecords <- function(data){
    data %>% 
        mutate(Time = map2(StartTime, EndTime, ~seq(.x, .y-1))) %>% 
        unnest() %>% 
        select(EventId, Day, Time)
}

makeIncrementalRecords(df)
#   EventId Day    Time
# 1       1 Mon       1
# 2       1 Mon       2
# 3       2 Tues      2
# 4       2 Tues      3
# 5       2 Tues      4
```

Or if you want to keep it with `data.table`

```
makeIncrementalRecords2 <- function(data){
    data.table::setDT(data)[, .(Time = seq(StartTime, EndTime-1, by = 1)), by = .(EventId, Day)]
}

makeIncrementalRecords2(df)
#    EventId  Day Time
# 1:       1  Mon    1
# 2:       1  Mon    2
# 3:       2 Tues    2
# 4:       2 Tues    3
# 5:       2 Tues    4
```