# Creating custom R package with data.table custom function

Tags: r, r-package

I wanted to create a package following these very clear and simple instructions, https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/ However the following function works when it is not inside a package, but does not work when in a package.

To reproduce this, run the following command in your default folder:**Step 1**

```
library("devtools")
library(roxygen2)
create_package("poweR")
```

This will take you to a new window and in that window: **Step 2**

**exploit_url.R: Create and Copy this to R folder of package**

```
#' @import data.table
exploit_url <- function(df, href, target, anchor, new_col) {
  return(df[, (new_col) := paste0("<a href='", df[[href]], "' target='", target, "'>", df[[anchor]], "</a>", "<br>")][, c(1, 3:6, 8)])
}
```

Then run the following commands after creating and copying/saving file to R folder of package:

```
library(devtools)
use_package("data.table")
document()
build()
install()
```

Close that window and go back to window Step 1

```
library("poweR")
library(data.table)
DT <- structure(list(cveid = c("CVE-2008-4726", "CVE-2018-18798", "CVE-2001-0791", 
                             "CVE-2005-1823"), EDB_ID = c("6804", "45727", "20893", "25766"
                             ), Type = c("remote", "webapps", "remote", "webapps"), 
                   Platform = c("Windows","PHP", "Windows", "PHP"), 
                   E_DB_Verified = c("Verified", "Waiting verification", "Verified", "Verified"), 
                   E_DB_Published = c("2008-10-22", "2018-10-29", "2001-05-24", "2005-05-30"), 
                   url = c("https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/6804/","https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/45727/", 
                           "https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/20893/", "https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/25766/")), 
                   class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))


DT <- exploit_url(DT, "url", '_blank', "E_DB_Verified", "exploitdburl")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in exploit_url(DT, "url", "_blank", "E_DB_Verified", "exploitdburl") : 
  could not find function "exploit_url"
```

Is there something I am missing? Any suggestions will be welcome

Comment: provide your NAMESPACE file, it is the second most important piece of a package just after DESCRIPTION file

Comment: doesn't seems to be related to data.table, maybe you just forget to put `export(exploit_url)` in your NAMESPACE file?

Comment: @jangorecki I had `#' @ export` in my .R file. I will try that and your suggestion

Comment: What matters is your NAMESPACE file, not hints which are used to generate it

Comment: Your updated question is basically a new problem (the warning), thus should be posted as new question

Comment: @jangorecki I will do as you suggested to post a new question and separate them.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions worked for me and I was able to get things working

Answer (score 1):

Solved it based on comments from `@jangorecki`.