# Custom package throwing Invalid .internal.selfref detected data.table warning

Tags: r, r-package

Please see this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720520/creating-custom-r-package-with-data-table-custom-function/56726914#56726914) to get background on this issue. Based on comments from `@jangorecki`, I made following changes to the `**exploit_url.R**` like so:'

```
#' @export
#' @import data.table
exploit_url <- function(df, href, target, anchor, new_col) {
  return(df[, (new_col) := paste0("<a href='", df[[href]], "' target='", target, "'>", df[[anchor]], "</a>", "<br>")][, c(1, 3:6, 8)])
}
```

Follow Step 1 and Step 2 and everything is taken care of in `NAMESPACE` and `DESCRIPTION`. I am getting a warning message, with correct output.

NAMESPACE:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

import(data.table)
```

DESCRIPTION:

```
Package: poweR
Title: What the Package Does (One Line, Title Case)
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: 
    person(given = "First",
           family = "Last",
           role = c("aut", "cre"),
           email = "first.last@example.com",
           comment = c(ORCID = "YOUR-ORCID-ID"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
License: What license it uses
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Imports: 
    data.table
RoxygenNote: 6.1.1.9000
```

Output:
[image]

New Warning:

```
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(df, , `:=`((new_col), paste0("<a href='", df[[href]],  :
  Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. If this message doesn't help, please report your use case to the data.table issue tracker so the root cause can be fixed or this message improved.
```

Answer (score 0):

After I read the warning message I realized that it could be because of the way I created the `data.table`. Further research lead me to this [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133522/invalid-internal-selfref-in-data-table) that helped me make sense of what I was doing wrong.

I used following code:

```
# Create dataframe for testing
dput(head(cve_exploitdb[c(1:4),]))
```

Based on the post, we should avoid copying a data.table into a list. Out of curiousity, I ran the the package function on the original data.table and it worked with no warning message