# Using .() or list() to select a data table column from within an R package

Tags: r, data.table, package

I have created a package in R. The default `hello.R` file created by RStudio contains only the code below.

```
# Test function
foo <- function(x, y){
  # Create data table
  dt <- data.table::data.table(x = x, y = y)

  #Check
  print(data.table::is.data.table(dt))
  print(dt)
  print(dt[, .(x)])
}
```

I then run `devtools::load_all()` to load the package and try running this function as follows:

```
foo(1:10, 1:10)
# [1] TRUE
#     x  y
# 1:  1  1
# 2:  2  2
# 3:  3  3
# 4:  4  4
# 5:  5  5
# 6:  6  6
# 7:  7  7
# 8:  8  8
# 9:  9  9
# 10: 10 10
# Error in .(x) : could not find function "."
```

So, `TRUE` indicates that it creates a `data.table`, the `data.table` is printed and looks good, but it fails when I try to use `.` to see just one column (i.e., `x`).

Okay, perhaps my package doesn't know about `.` because `data.table` isn't loaded, so I'll use `list()` instead which is equivalent to `.()` according to the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html).

```
# Test function
foo <- function(x, y){
  # Create data table
  dt <- data.table::data.table(x = x, y = y)

  #Check
  print(data.table::is.data.table(dt))
  print(dt)
  print(dt[, list(x)])
}
```

and I run `devtools::load_all()` then call the function as before.

```
foo(1:10, 1:10)
# [1] TRUE
#     x  y
# 1:  1  1
# 2:  2  2
# 3:  3  3
# 4:  4  4
# 5:  5  5
# 6:  6  6
# 7:  7  7
# 8:  8  8
# 9:  9  9
# 10: 10 10
# Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Hmmm. Weird, as `list` is a `base` function so clearly the package knows about it. Why can I not select a column using the usual `data.table` syntax from within my R package?

Comment: When I run it in my console the function runs fine. Instead of `load_all` have you tried to install and restart the package or check package? Can you make data.table a dependency?

Comment: Yep, you're right about the dependency. The solution is to [RTM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html) and include `data.table` in the DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE files.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10527072/4550695

Comment: Thanks, @MikkoMarttila – I'll mark it as a dupe.

Comment: If you think there is room for improvement on the [Importing `data.table` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html), please [file an issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues) :)

Comment: @MichaelChirico No, I think the vignette is quite clear. The problem was purely that I didn't read it!

Comment: we havent done too well advertising it! 