# R data.table error: invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: r, list, matrix, data.table, subscript

I have checked other questions but none of them seem to apply to my problem with `data.table`.

It seems an easy enough problem: I have a data matrix, and I just want to calculate the mean per column, aggregating using a different column, and I want to explicitly use `data.table`.

I have the following matrix:

```
> datam <- cbind(matrix(rexp(100), 10), IN=c(rep(1,2), rep(2,3), rep(3,2), rep(4,1), rep(5,2)))
> datam
                                                                                                                  IN
 [1,] 0.20650931 0.6997571 0.97464213 0.60447629 1.58775119 0.95589192 0.06428668 0.63871505 1.9710147 1.47914062  1
 [2,] 1.13443868 0.1452056 0.12636405 1.27150736 0.22075150 1.14576889 2.42279821 0.27011710 1.1154945 0.01105555  1
 [3,] 0.14441902 1.9815460 0.44642791 0.30314789 0.86700105 0.08443948 0.11991152 0.87640052 0.5047499 0.29289425  2
 [4,] 2.77837206 0.5182024 0.01790841 1.93901641 0.06103524 1.41916299 0.22346853 1.01386631 4.4132946 1.22985369  2
 [5,] 0.34792681 0.1992605 0.52433916 0.77726244 3.52407696 1.20707416 0.61440217 1.17350349 1.1507378 0.10822862  2
 [6,] 0.04152492 3.0030461 0.63160154 0.58567018 1.40882345 0.64502956 0.09270774 0.48659474 2.1546318 0.60766586  3
 [7,] 0.60525099 0.2917629 1.83211987 1.14103166 0.44245533 0.17263702 0.12986408 0.06746046 0.1737246 2.15982163  3
 [8,] 0.58719066 0.8218078 2.62051296 1.14004448 0.28344820 2.19568102 0.16395865 0.30511205 1.0641123 1.71593894  4
 [9,] 0.15103229 0.2349367 0.68708366 0.04129689 0.45221114 0.39821837 1.02286218 0.59763803 0.8831383 0.03271210  5
[10,] 0.26633984 0.9035208 0.27722630 0.36636195 0.87703820 1.49207955 0.05097381 1.16625317 0.3791779 0.26460207  5
```

I want the mean per column based on the grouping by the last `IN` column, for which I use `data.table` the following way:

```
> dd <- data.table(datam)
> dd[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=IN]
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

You see above the error I got:

> Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'

What am I doing wrong and how to solve this error? I used that `data.table` command many times before and never gave me a problem, is it that `data.table` has changed its syntax or something?

Many thanks!

Comment: `dd[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=IN]` works fine for me without any error.

Comment: It has always worked for me too... I don't understand where the problem is now

Comment: Did you try restarting R and checking?

Comment: Ok it works on a clean session, but not inside my script where I need to do it... is there any known package or something that might clash with this?

Comment: Have you defined your own `mean` function or have you used `mean` as a variable in your script somewhere?

Comment: Not really... but I just rebooted and somehow it works... Will notify again if it crashes or I can spot the cause of this behavior

Comment: No, I still find the problem in my script... can there be some clash with `plyr` or something? I use in my script a custom package that uses it...

Comment: Now it says `Error in lapply(.SD, mean) : object '.SD' not found`... this really makes no sense to me

Comment: @DaniCee, the last one seems like your data.frame is not defined as a data.table. Can change with  `setDT()`

Comment: No, the problem is I use data.table inside a package... I follow the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527072/using-data-table-package-inside-my-own-package but it only works if I do library(package) first... I'm going to open a new thread

Comment: Before the line where you use `.SD`, define `.SD <- NULL`. I can't explain what's going on exactly, but R sees `.SD` and inside of your data table call, and assumes it's a variable or function, so gives up without trying. If you define `.SD` first, it does not give up and tries--with success! (Hopefully...)