# R: cannot make use of `data.table`'s environment, base environment and global environment all at once

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the dummy example below: I want to run a model on a range of subsets of the data.table in a loop, and want to specify the exact line to iterate as a string (with an iterator `i`)

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(X = runif(100), Y = runif(100))

f1 <- function(code) {
  
  for (i in c(20,30,50)) {
    
    eval(parse(text = code))
    
  }
  
}

f1("lm(X ~ Y, data = DT[sample(.N, i)])")
```

Obviously this doesn't return any output as `lm()` is merely evaluated in the background 3 times. The actual use case is more convoluted, but this is meant to be a theoretical simplification of it.

The example above, nonetheless, works fine. The problems begin when the function `f1` is included in the package, instead of being defined in the global environment. If I'm not mistaken, in this case `f1` is defined in the package's base env. Then, calling `f1` from global env gives the error: `Error in [.data.frame(x, i) : undefined columns selected`. R can correctly access iterator `i` in its base env and `DT` in the global env, but cannot access the column by name inside data.table's square brackets.

I tried experimenting by setting `envir` and `enclos` arguments to `eval()` to `baseenv()`, `globalenv()`, `parent.frame()`, but haven't managed to find a combination that works.

For example, setting `envir = globalenv()` seems to result in accessing `DT` and `i`, but not `X` and `Y` from the `DT` inside `lm()`. Setting `envir = baseenv()` we lose the global env and cannot access `DT` (`envir = baseenv(), enclos = globalenv()` doesn't change it). Using `envir = list(baseenv(), globalenv())` results in not being able to access anything inside data.table's square brackets, I think, error message: "Error in [.data.frame(x, i) : undefined columns selected".

Comment: Your code is applied in the `for` loop.  You may need to initialize an object to store the output and return the value

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that variables are resolved lexicographically. You could try passing in the expression and the substituting the value of `i` specifically before evaluating. This would take care of eliminating the need for explicit parsing.

```
f1 <- function(code) {
  code <- substitute(code)
  
  for (i in c(20,30,50)) {
    cmd <- do.call("substitute", list(code, list(i=i)))
    print(cmd)
    result <- eval.parent(cmd)
    print(result)
  }
}

f1(lm(X ~ Y, data = DT[sample(.N, i)]))
```

Comment: Thanks @Mrflick , this fixed the eval issue, but created or revealed another issue elsewhere. Inside `f1` further down I have `timings <- data.table(...)` which creates a data.table, and works fine. (`f1` includes a call `library(data.table)`). But then the operation `timings[, t := ...]` fails due to `Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and \`:=\`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways.` data.table is a bit unusual in that it not only defines functions, but also own syntax and operators inside sq brackets. `timings` is used only internally inside `f1`.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10529888/2753688) fixed the above.

Comment: I take it back, the eval issue isn't fixed. What I am really trying to do is measure evaluation times by: `start <- Sys.time(); eval(...); t <- Sys.time() - start`. In my original version it wouldn't even evaluate if `f1` is defined inside a package. In your version it seems to "run" without error, but evidently doen't evaluate, since running times for each call are measured in fractions of a second, instead of several sec/min, as expected.

Comment: Final upd: ironically, the ultimate fix turned out to be to go back to my original version, `eval(parse(text = code))` which started working perfectly fine after I've made the package [data.table-aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10529888/2753688).