# calling data.table functions when developing a package

Tags: r, data.table

I'm developing a package that uses data.table, but when I call certain data.table functions, such as `DT[, ..colnames]` or `DT[grepl("foo", col)]` or `DT[, .(colname)]` I get errors like:
"colnames not found" or "could not find function "."". These errors are being called from data.frame so I guess when R looks for the functions, it's looking for them inside data.frame instead of data.table. When I run `class(DT)`, I get `"data.table" "data.frame"`

I also tried `DT[, data.table::.(colname)]` but get the error that '.' is not an exported object from namespace:data.table.

I haven't run into this behavior outside of the context of package development. Can someone provide me with some advice?

Comment: Old answer but can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527072/using-data-table-package-inside-my-own-package

Comment: Does your package import data.table (in DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE)?

Comment: I had import data.table in DESCRIPTION but not in NAMESPACE. This was the issue, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, the solution was to import data.table in both DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE. I also found this vignette to be helpful - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html

This resource was also helpful:
https://r-pkgs.org/dependencies-mindset-background.html#sec-dependencies-NAMESPACE-file